# Take element that are only in one table from a join in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables, network_permissions and device_permissions like this:

```
NETWORK_PERMISSIONS
user_id network_id  perm
1        1           3
1        2           4
2        3           3
2        2           1
3        2           1
4        2           3


DEVICES_PERMISSIONS
user_id network_id  device_id   perm
1        2           2           1
2        2           2           1
```

Now, I would take only user_id that for the net=2 are in the network_permissions table (within users with perm=3), but not in the device_permissions.

I would in this case the result is: 3 because is the user that have perm!=3 in the network_permission table for the net=2, but is not present in the device_permissions table.

Sorry if it's confused... Thank you for the help.

Comment: How do you get the ones that are in both?

Comment: With a join.. I think

Comment: do you expect NETWORK_PERMISSIONS.network_id=2 and NETWORK_PERMISSIONS.perm=3 and user not in DEVICES_PERMISSIONS is this correct?

Comment: So, you want those users that has `perm != 3` and is not presented in the other table? if so there is two users id's that satisy this condition user 3 and 4 not only the user 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT n.user_id 
FROM network_permissions AS n
Left JOIN devices_permissions AS d ON n.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE d.user_id is null and n.network_id=2 and n.perm=3

Comment: Yes! Thank you! But with a correction: n.perm<>3 so I exlude that users. Correct the answer! :)

Comment: in question you mentioned users with perm=3

Comment: I want take users with perm!=3 . Sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
Select NETWORK_PERMISSIONS.network_id FROM NETWORK_PERMISSIONS LEFT JOIN DEVICES_PERMISSIONS on NETWORK_PERMISSIONS.network_id = DEVICES_PERMISSIONS.network_id AND NETWORK_PERMISSIONS.user_id = DEVICES_PERMISSIONS.user_id
```